# Need help in converting C++ to javascript

Tags: javascript, c++

I'm constructing a javascript indicator for my client and they gave me below C++ code from their old system. I have never done C++ program before. Below is the part of the C++ code. What I want to know is in the line
`if (it3 != d1Swing.end() && it3->x == h[i].x) --(it1 = it2 = it3);`  what is the meaning of --(it1 = it2 = it3)? What will it looks like in javascript?

```
vector<PTPoint::PTIndexPoint> dnSwing;
list<PTPoint::PTIndexPoint> hq, lq;
vector<PTPoint::PTIndexPoint>::iterator it1 = d1Swing.begin(), it2 = d1Swing.begin(), it3 = ++d1Swing.begin();

//
// more code here
//
for (int i = 0; i < period; ++i)
{
    while (!hq.empty() && hq.back().y < h[i].y) hq.pop_back();
    hq.push_back(h[i]);
    while (!lq.empty() && lq.back().y > l[i].y) lq.pop_back();
    lq.push_back(l[i]);

    if (it3 != d1Swing.end() && it3->x == h[i].x) --(it1 = it2 = it3);
    //
    // more code here
    //
} 

//
// more code here
//
p->swap(dnSwing);
```

Thanks in advance.

tslin

Comment: You'd better post the original C++ code, and separately your attempted translation to JavaScript.

Comment: Don't translate. Instead, figure out what the code does and replicate the behavior using JavaScript features.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestion. I've updated my question. @Cheersandhth.-Alf I removed javascript part as it is not necessary and not related to the question.

Comment: @Rakete1111, thanks for the suggestion. I was translating it to understand their program. I just don't get the logic with those syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that their previous programmer loved being "clever".

The value of an assignment is a reference to the object that was assigned to, and assignment associates to the right.

```
--(it1 = it2 = it3)
```

is

```
--(it1 = (it2 = it3))
```

and it's intended to assign the value of `it3` to `it2` and `it1`, then decrement `it1`.
(I have a hunch that this may be undefined, which is a thing that happens frequently when you're being clever in C++.)

`it1` is apparently intended to be "one step behind" `it2`.

A more reasonable way to write that is

```
it2 = it3;
it1 = it2 - 1;
```

(In JavaScript, I suspect that you need to work with array indices rather than iterators to accomplish the same thing.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I thought it was it1 = it2, it2 = it3, it3 - 1; Yes, I will be using array and index.